# is it okay 4 years old used UPS Battery filling sulfuric Acid insted of Distilled water?

Tags: batteries, ups, backup

[image][image]I've 1250VA UPS where I found 2 battery (12V-9AH). which Is used for 4 and years more.
When I brought this UPS it gave almost 80 to 90 minutes backup but now it only lasts for 15 min.

so I decided to replace the battery, but when I opened up the caps both the batteries are dry (no liquid on it). still, it has 13.5V after full charge. Is it a good idea to refill the sulfuric Acid instead of distill water?

and what if I replace UPS battery to Car Battery 12V 35AH?
[image]

Comment: Don't invest any time or money in that battery, it's a no-name brand. Buy a new matching one from Yuasa or Exide.

Comment: If you try to revive it, add distilled water, NOT acid.

Answer (score 3):

A UPS uses **sealed** lead acid batteries (SLA), those are not intended to be refilled.
They are filled with a elektrolyte gel instead of liquid.
Refilling could theoretically work, if you're able to remove the gel. Which means removing the top, which is ultrasonically welded.

The rubber caps you see there are intended as pressure relief valve.

When adding water you lose the ability to operate them in all orientations.

Replacing the battery with a car battery may work, but do not expect improved runtime, that is not what car batteries are designed for. Car batteries excel at high current, not high capacity.

tl;dr Just buy a new battery. It's $20. ($5/y)

Comment: I've opened rubber and saw empty should i pour distrilled water or sulphuric acid

Comment: fasten your seatbelts guys, we are just going to witness something about batteries being learnt the hard way

Comment: @PratapShrestha You should add recycler fluid.